# Show/hide div via JavaScript based upon data value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid of images in divs with data attributes.  I'd like to be able to show/hide them via CSS based upon a input text match.  I loop through the number of divs with the matching class, then loop through the words in the input array and finally loop through the words in the data attribute field. It looks like the DOM is losing track of the outer index by the time I find a match between the two inner array text values.  The console sees the three loop index values but the JavaScript show command is not invoked.  The show command does work if I hard code the index value (0).  This feels like a really messy way to do this.

HTML:

```
        <img
          src="images/game thumb 216px-1.png"
          alt="Photo of hotline game"
          class="gallery__photo photo1"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        class="gallery__item"
        data-new="true"
        data-top="true"
        data-value="2 neon jungle"
      >
        <img
          src="images/game thumb 216px-2.png"
          alt="Photo of neon jungle game"
          class="gallery__photo photo2"
        />
      </div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
        //build object containing all gallery__item divs
        //let galleryitems = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery__item");
        
        //assign search input words to variable
        let myInputWords = $("#search").val();

        //create array of input words
        let myInputWordsArray = myInputWords.split(" ");

        //create array of gallery words
        let myGalleryItemsArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < galleryitems.length; i++) {
          //fetch data-value attribute value
          let myAttributeValue = galleryitems[i].getAttribute("data-value");
          //add to gallery item array
          myGalleryItemsArray.push(myAttributeValue);
        }

        //loop through input words array - outer
        //loop through gallery words array - inner
        let i, k, m = 0;
        //loop through input element words array
        for (i = 0; i < myInputWordsArray.length; i++) {
          //loop through gallery items array
          for ( k = 0; k < myGalleryItemsArray.length; k++) {
            //loop through each gallery item which can contain multiple words and create a new array
            let myGalleryItemArray = myGalleryItemsArray[k].split(" ");
              //loop through each gallery item array element's words
              for ( m = 0; m < myGalleryItemArray.length; m++) {
              //console.log(myInputWordsArray[i]);
              //console.log(myGalleryItemArray[m]);
              //if the outer input array word matches the inner data word change the CSS display to block else set the CSS display to none
              if (myInputWordsArray[i] === myGalleryItemArray[m]) {
                 galleryitems[k].style.display = "block";
                //console.log(galleryitems[k]);
              } else {
                galleryitems[k].style.display = "none";
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you find the correct word, you still fetching your current gallery item then your div can be displayed for a brief moment and be hidden on the next loop iteration because the word is not correct that time.

Just add a `break` when you have found the correct word for leaving the current `for` loop. Here's a working example (https://jsfiddle.net/da7zs9wo/) :

```
            //build object containing all gallery__item divs
        let galleryitems = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery__item");
        
        //assign search input words to variable
          let myInputWords = $("#search").val();

          //create array of input words
          let myInputWordsArray = myInputWords.split(" ");

          //create array of gallery words
          let myGalleryItemsArray = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < galleryitems.length; i++) {
            //fetch data-value attribute value
            let myAttributeValue = galleryitems[i].getAttribute("data-value");
            //add to gallery item array
            myGalleryItemsArray.push(myAttributeValue);
          }

          //loop through input words array - outer
          //loop through gallery words array - inner
          let i, k, m = 0;
          //loop through input element words array
          for (i = 0; i < myInputWordsArray.length; i++) {
            //loop through gallery items array
            for ( k = 0; k < myGalleryItemsArray.length; k++) {
              //loop through each gallery item which can contain multiple words and create a new array
              let myGalleryItemArray = myGalleryItemsArray[k].split(" ");
                //loop through each gallery item array element's words
                for ( m = 0; m < myGalleryItemArray.length; m++) {
                //console.log(myInputWordsArray[i]);
                //console.log(myGalleryItemArray[m]);
                //if the outer input array word matches the inner data word change the CSS display to block else set the CSS display to none
                if (myInputWordsArray[i] === myGalleryItemArray[m]) {
                   galleryitems[k].style.display = "block";
                   break; // End loop for this item when we found the correct word
                  //console.log(galleryitems[k]);
                } else {
                  galleryitems[k].style.display = "none";
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

You should consider using the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) ES6 method on your array to avoid a loopfest.